# Should i use mil when throwing an exception

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have an object with the following CTOR:

```
//m_minute is a data member
Minute::Minute(size_t _minuteInHour ): m_minute( _minuteInHour )
{
    if (_minuteInHour >= 60)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("only 60 minutes in one hour, 0 - 59");
    }
}
```

since i am checking the value only in the body, should i initiate the data member in the MIL or should i use a function that checks for value legality and throws exception if illegal or returns a legal value?

```
size_t CheckMinuteLegality( size_t _minute ) 
{
    if ( _minute >= 60 )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("only 60 minutes in one hour, 0 - 59");
    }
    _return minute; 
}
```

the question is should i:
a. call the function from the MIL
b. use MIL and than test value
c. test value and then assign it to data member without using MIL.

thanks

Comment: Does it really make a difference? The object isn't considered initialized either way at the end of it all. Still, a good first question IMO.

Comment: Use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) to represent Date/Time values portably in c++.

Comment: I have always followed the standard of validating the value passed into the constructor and assign it to member there. You could use a separate function to validate it and throw exception in constructor based on return value from function. Either way it doesn't matter really, up to you.

Comment: The first one seems simpler and clearer to me, so that's what I'd do. You can always extract a helper function later if the validation is particularly complicated. But it's a matter of taste really. (The first version works better when the validation needs to look at multiple values - e.g. a + b must be < 100.)

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `size_t` but just `int` here, so that you can more safely detect negative values.

Comment: Hi, 
size_t won't allow for negative values, not sure i understand why int is better. Can you please elaborate?